# python: Packages in user-site not overriding dist-packages on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, path, installation, package

I use ubuntu 13.04. When developing in python, I sometimes wish to use newer versions of some packages than those shipped with ubuntu. In these cases, the method I'm used to is to install the package only to my user account, for example like this (for the package `six`):

```
$ pip install --user --upgrade six
```

This correctly installs the newest version (1.4.1) of six somewhere in my home directory. However, when I load the package I just installed, python chooses the version installed system-wide:

```
$ python -c "import six; print six; print six.__version__"                                                     
<module 'six' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.pyc'>
1.2.0
```

This is in my opinion odd behaviour; packages installed manually by the user should be preferred. I have tried the same procedure on Arch Linux, where the user-site package is loaded first. My `sys.path`:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.path"                                                                       
['', '/home/jostein/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enaml-0.5.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/home/jostein/Programming/scikit-image', '/home/jostein/Programming/reconstruct', '/home/jostein/Programming/ptychography', '/home/jostein/Programming', '/home/jostein', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/jostein/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` appears before anything user-related, which is probably the cause of the problem.

Does anyone know of a good way to allow preferring user-installed packages over the system-wide installs on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having dist packages before users packages actually makes sense IMHO. But anyway, you have two options here, the bad one and the right one.

The bad one is to redefine your PYTHONPATH environment variable to put your local package's dir before site-wide packages. It's as simple as this, but don't complain when your system breaks because you shadowed a critical package with some incompatible version.

The right way to try out specific versions of a package without breaking anything is of course to use virtualenv.